# LINQ query left join multiple columns with null check failing

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

`pt` and `emod` are both in-memory queries returning a  `tElementRowValuesDBModel` type.  Both are not executed until after this statement shown.

If I debug and look at the returned results separately, both run successfully and return values.

Could I use `Except` or `not in` sub-query, sure!, but I just want to understand if this is a bug or there's a workaround.

Strangely, if i remove any reference to the `tempe` object, everything runs OK.
Am I missing something?

```
var RealNewNodes = from p in pt
                   join e1 in emod on new{X1 = p.tElementRowsDBModelID, X2 = p.tAttributesDBModelID, X3 = p.AttributeValue} equals new {X1 = e1.tElementRowsDBModelID, X2 = e1.tAttributesDBModelID, X3 = e1.AttributeValue } into tempt
                   from tempe in tempt.DefaultIfEmpty() 
                   where tempe == null //if i remove this line, works OK
                   select new tElementRowValuesDBModel{
                       tElementRowsDBModelID = p.tElementRowsDBModelID,
                       tAttributesDBModelID = p.tAttributesDBModelID,
                       AttributeValue = p.AttributeValue,
                       ID = (tempe!=null ? 1 : 0 )//if i remove this line, works OK
                   };
```

Comment: In what way is it failing?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Is this EF Core? If yes, what version?

Comment: @IvanStoev Hi the reference in the csproj file is pointing to 1.1.*

Comment: There were/are many EF Core bugs related to `left outer join`s, you might check their issue tracker or try if it happens in *the latest and greatest* (v1.1.2 currently)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps if you didn't do the join, since your `join`/`where` means find `pt` without matches, it would work:

```
var RealNewNodes = from p in pt
               where !emod.Any(e1 => p.tElementRowsDBModelID == e1.tElementRowsDBModelID && p.tAttributesDBModelID == e1.tAttributesDBModelID && p.AttributeValue == e1.AttributeValue)
               select new tElementRowValuesDBModel {
                   tElementRowsDBModelID = p.tElementRowsDBModelID,
                   tAttributesDBModelID = p.tAttributesDBModelID,
                   AttributeValue = p.AttributeValue,
                   ID = 1
               };
```

Comment: Thanks, haven't been able to try it out yet, will let you know if this works as soon as works allows

Comment: I swear... i just had to reboot my computer and my original question is now working fine... however this answer also provides the same result.  Thanks